# Combine the date format of a number with other text into one string

Tags: string, date, google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I need to combine a date with a string. These are the contents of my three cells:

```
cell   formula      shows
A1     05/11/2014   2014-11-05 (the cell is formatted as date)
B1     JS           JS (text)
C1     A1 & B1      41948JS
```

I need cell C1 to display `2014-11-05JS` - i.e., a combined string containing the date.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Ahhh sorry, will edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
=left(A1,5)&mid(A1,6,2)&right(A1,3)&B1
```

(I am assuming there are typos in your question).

Comment: The only one workig (others give me the same result I got in the original example). Actually, I havent tried the helpYou option, I realize.

Comment: What about =TEXT(A1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&B1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Use CONCATENATE function.

Example:

> = CONCATENATE(A5, " ", A6)

Importantly, In default date will not properly get appended. You need to select date field(s) and format it is "Plain Text". Option can seen at Format >> Number >> Plain Text

More functions are given [here](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CONCATENATE` (or `CONCAT`) function. Each of them has advantages:

- `CONCAT` can combine number and string
- `CONCATENATE` can use many arguments at the same time

so you can use

- `CONCAT` many times

or

- `CONCATENATE` + many `TO_TEXT`

Extract the date components using `YEAR`, `MONTH` and `DAY` functions.